# CPP/ROS: Including external packages does only work in the package itself, but not when importin the package into another

Tags: c++, cmake, ros

I am using ROS.
Hey Guys, lets assume I have 10 Packages: pkg

> pkg1, pkg2,..., pkg10

, where the next package depends on the previous one:

> For example: pkg10 depends on pkg9

In package 1 I included an external library using the following commands in the CmakeLists:

```
include_directories // for the header 
find_library // for finding the .a 
target_link_libraries // for linking the .a
```

And I can succesfully build and run pkg1. But when I am trying to build package10, I get the following errors:

> .../pkg1.so: undefined reference to functionFromExternalLib()
> ...

I have already tried to add the external library into the CmakeLists of pkg10 but that does not fix the problem.

What is my problem here why can it not find the external library?

Comment: Looks like your external lib is not linked. Thin about correct usage of CATKIN_DEPEND and DEPEND: https://answers.ros.org/question/58498/what-is-the-purpose-of-catkin_depends/

Comment: @Fruchtzwerg First of all thanks for the fast answer. I am really struggling with this problem. I mean yes it seems like it is not correctly linked in package10. But it is in package1, and package1 was correctly built with the external package. But why does package10 not integrate it. And whats with the packages between 1 and 10